# Substitute parts of CWD in bash prompt (Git Bash)

Tags: bash, git-bash

This is in Git Bash

I am trying to make my prompt go from

```
/c/folder $
```

to

```
c->folder $
```

What would I put in my `.bashrc` to make this work? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do arbitrary things to your prompt by setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` to a function that assigns `PS1`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="setmyprompt"
setmyprompt() {
  dir="${PWD#/}"
  dir="${dir//\//->}"
  PS1="$dir \\\$ "
}
```